# Closure magic in higher-order functions.

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, higher-order-functions

It's easy to know how to assign a global variable to an inner function - which would make the global variable a function itself thats equal to the inner function - but how does the interpreter know how to call an argument from the inner function by using the code below?

```
def outer(arg):
    def inner(arg2):
        print(arg, ',', arg2):
    return inner

a = outer(‘outer arg’)

print(a) # .inner at 0x109bd0048
a('inner arg') # Output: outer arg, inner arg
```

Doing `print(a)`, we see the variable/function `a` becomes the inner function.

What I don't understand, is how assigning the `a` variable to the outer function targets the inner function and argument with the code, `a(‘inner argument’))`

Is it somehow implicitly calling the inner function without explicitly stating it?

Is it doing something like this:

```
a = outer('outer arg')inner('inner arg')
```

Where is the python source code behind this magic?

Comment: While requests for links to external resource (like Python source code) are off-topic, you might find [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix6MTSemdUU) entertaining.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks for the link, although I got the gist of closures and HOFs, the voodoo behind it has been piquing at me. What forum would a question like this be appropriate to ask at? Does the video contain a 'How' the interpreter allow for `a = outer('outer')` to run the inner function with `a('inner')`

Comment: I don't know whether there is a "python internals" Stack Exchange page... Do you really need a forum for that? Wouldn't just cloning python's source code and grepping for the relevant keywords do the job? How deep in the codebase can it be buried... I haven't watched this specific lecture for Python, because I've already watched analogous lectures for other languages, but the lecture seemed to point in the right direction.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Probably not. As long as it serves it's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment, so I have to write an answer...

From the excellent "Fluent Python" by Luciano Ramalho:

> "...Python keeps the names of local and free variables in the
>   __code__ attribute that represents the compiled body of the
>   function"
>
> "To summarize: a closure is a function that retains the bindings of
>   the free variables that exist when the function is defined, so that
>   they can be used later when the function is invoked and the defining
>   scope is no longer available"

I added a couple of rows to your code to visualize this:

```
def outer(arg):
    def inner(arg2):
        print(arg, ',', arg2)
    print (inner.__code__.co_freevars)
    print (inner.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
    return inner
```

Which prints the following:

```
In [169]: outer('outer arg')
('arg',)
outer arg
```

So as you can see the value of arg is preserved even after the function has gone out of scope, since it is a free variable. The binding for arg is kept in the __closure__ attribute.

This is only a hint for further reading, I am by no means an expert.

Comment: While I should have stated my question to render this specific answer, I really appreciate the quality and clarity of it. Using dunders to show that they preserve the original value of the first argument was very helpful. Unless a better one comes up, I'll accept it as the solution. Danke